# Extend/Implement a class/interface that was loaded using reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, interface

Let's say we load the classes X and Y using reflection.
For Y we also obtain an instance I.
Now we want to call the method M on I which expects an instance of type X.
Furthermore we assume that X is abstract.

Is it possible to derive from X so that we can call M?
Same question goes for interfaces in case X is an interface instead of an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an interface, you could create a [dynamic proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) to act like an instance of an implementing class. You could use [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) or [Javassist](http://www.javassist.org/) to do the same thing for an abstract class.